# java 9: In module-info.java do i have to again mention packages((as requires) that are already being imported in sources

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

working with java 9 modules, if i am using java.xml in my code...
1) i will import xml package using import statement...
2) if i don't  mention that this package is required in the module declaration of my module...
 - will the compilation of my module work.. ??
i would guess... no... and on mentioning that xml package is required on module-info.java... it might work.
so.. what I am wondering is... is that not redundancy... every importing package is implicitly... required. (unless i need to understand module even better)

Is there a way to mention that all imported packages are required in module declaration, other wise it could be a long list to mention in module-info.java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, in `module-info.java` you mention modules, not packages. E.g. `java.xml` is a module which contains about 25 packages. So, if your module uses 10 packages from the `java.xml` module, you don't have to repeat that 10 times in `module-info.java`, you write `requires java.xml` just once. So, that huge list of dependencies is not huge actually.

If you really want to skip all those declarations, you can just not create `module-info.java` (but I don't recommend to do that). A module that does not have `module-info.java` is called an automatic module and it implicitly requires all other modules.

Comment: that's gr8 explanation. gr8.  _"However, java.xml is not in the module graph by default, so you have to pass"_ . My understanding is only `java.base` is available by default. What module graph are you referring. Any example?

Comment: The _java.xml_ module is included by default (try it with `java --limit-modules java.se --list-modules`), so not need to worry there. By the way, the confusion between modules and packages is why I use _italics_ for the former and `code formatting` for the latter.

Comment: @Nicolai You are right. I confused `java.xml` with `java.xml.bind` which is not included by default.

Answer (score 0):

#### solution (workaround)

*If you are **bothered** by having to write out each single `requires` again and again  

-- there is a faster way to **`requires *all*`** 

-- if you know Ahk & AhkSpy*

1. get [**AhkSpy**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/serzh82saratov/AhkSpy/master/AhkSpy.ahk)
2. open the **`module dependency`**
3. capture & copy **all** of them by AhkSpy
4. paste them all in `module-info.java`

[image]

---

#### sample code

(if you really dont know how to do the above, copy the following **sample** code may help you a bit)

```
  //  requires HikariCP;
  //  requires accessors.smart;
  //  requires android.json;
  requires antlr;
  //  requires assertj.core;
  requires attoparser;
  requires com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;
  requires com.sun.istack.runtime;
  requires com.sun.xml.txw2;
  requires dom4j;
  //  requires jackson.core;
  //  requires jackson.databind;
  //  requires jackson.datatype.jdk8;
  //  requires jackson.datatype.jsr310;
  //  requires jackson.module.parameter.names;
  requires jakarta.activation;
  requires java.annotation;
  requires java.base;
  requires java.compiler;
  requires java.datatransfer;
  requires java.desktop;
  requires java.instrument;
  requires java.logging;
  requires java.management;
  requires java.management.rmi;
  requires java.naming;
  requires java.net.http;
  requires java.persistence;
  requires java.prefs;
  requires java.rmi;
  requires java.scripting;
  requires java.se;
  requires java.security.jgss;
  requires java.security.sasl;
  requires java.smartcardio;
  requires java.sql;
  requires java.sql.rowset;
  requires java.transaction;
  requires java.transaction.xa;
  requires java.xml;
  requires java.xml.bind;
  requires java.xml.crypto;
  requires jdk.accessibility;
  requires jdk.attach;
  requires jdk.charsets;
  requires jdk.compiler;
  requires jdk.crypto.cryptoki;
  requires jdk.crypto.ec;
  requires jdk.crypto.mscapi;
  requires jdk.dynalink;
  requires jdk.editpad;
  requires jdk.hotspot.agent;
  requires jdk.httpserver;
  requires jdk.internal.ed;
  requires jdk.internal.jvmstat;
  requires jdk.internal.le;
  requires jdk.internal.opt;
  requires jdk.internal.vm.ci;
  requires jdk.internal.vm.compiler;
  requires jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management;
  requires jdk.jartool;
  requires jdk.javadoc;
  requires jdk.jcmd;
  requires jdk.jconsole;
  requires jdk.jdeps;
  requires jdk.jdi;
  requires jdk.jdwp.agent;
  requires jdk.jfr;
  requires jdk.jlink;
  requires jdk.jpackage;
  requires jdk.jshell;
  requires jdk.jsobject;
  requires jdk.jstatd;
  requires jdk.localedata;
  requires jdk.management;
  requires jdk.management.agent;
  requires jdk.management.jfr;
  requires jdk.naming.dns;
  requires jdk.naming.rmi;
  requires jdk.net;
  requires jdk.nio.mapmode;
  requires jdk.random;
  requires jdk.sctp;
  requires jdk.security.auth;
  requires jdk.security.jgss;
  requires jdk.unsupported;
  requires jdk.unsupported.desktop;
  requires jdk.xml.dom;
  requires jdk.zipfs;
  //  requires json.path;
  //  requires json.smart;
  //  requires jsonassert;
  requires jul.to.slf4j;
  //  requires log4j.api;
  requires logback.classic;
  requires logback.core;
  requires lombok;
  //  requires mysql.connector.j;
  requires org.apache.logging.slf4j;
  requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.core;
  requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.el;
  requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.websocket;
  //  requires org.apiguardian.api;
  requires org.aspectj.weaver;
  requires org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime;
  //  requires org.hamcrest;
  requires org.hibernate.commons.annotations;
  requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
  requires org.hibernate.orm.envers;
  requires org.jboss.jandex;
  requires org.jboss.logging;
  requires org.joda.time;
  //  requires org.junit.jupiter;
  //  requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
  //  requires org.junit.jupiter.engine;
  //  requires org.junit.jupiter.params;
  //  requires org.junit.platform.commons;
  //  requires org.junit.platform.engine;
  //  requires org.mockito;
  //  requires org.mockito.junit.jupiter;
  //  requires org.objectweb.asm;
  //  requires org.objenesis;
  //  requires org.opentest4j;
  requires org.slf4j;
  //  requires org.xmlunit;
  requires org.yaml.snakeyaml;
  requires spring.aop;
  requires spring.aspects;
  requires spring.beans;
  requires spring.boot;
  requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
  //  requires spring.boot.devtools;
  requires spring.boot.starter;
  requires spring.boot.starter.aop;
  requires spring.boot.starter.data.jpa;
  requires spring.boot.starter.jdbc;
  requires spring.boot.starter.json;
  requires spring.boot.starter.logging;
  //  requires spring.boot.starter.test;
  requires spring.boot.starter.thymeleaf;
  requires spring.boot.starter.tomcat;
  requires spring.boot.starter.web;
  //  requires spring.boot.test;
  //  requires spring.boot.test.autoconfigure;
  requires spring.context;
  requires spring.core;
  requires spring.data.commons;
  requires spring.data.envers;
  requires spring.data.jpa;
  requires spring.expression;
  requires spring.jcl;
  requires spring.jdbc;
  requires spring.orm;
  //  requires spring.test;
  requires spring.tx;
  requires spring.web;
  requires spring.webmvc;
  requires thymeleaf;
  requires thymeleaf.extras.java8time;
  requires thymeleaf.spring5;
  requires unbescape;
```

<sub>---

#### misc (-- following not important)

- idk why Eclipse doesnt support this automatic adding `import` to `module-info.java`.
- `module-info.java` is annoying in many aspects -- requires you do many more work -- idk why (not familiar with)

  - `requires transitive`
  - **missing** `requires` & program throws exception
  - conflict with some program design
- Eclipse can indeed **auto generate** `module-info.java` by: 
  right click the project > Configure > Create `module-info.java` 
  but insufficient in some cases
- related: [Why is exporting the entire module not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269581/why-is-exporting-the-entire-module-not-allowed)
- [[Ahk & AhkSpy (/ AccViewer) is a good tool]]</sub>